# How can I access elements within a shadow-DOM and/or iframe?

Tags: html, selenium, iframe, shadow-dom

I am currently trying to access an href-link through selenium Python. I haven't been able to access the `<a>` tag, nor the `<aza-subpage-fixed-footer>` to be honest. I believe that these elements are within a shadow-DOM or a iframe, but I don't know how to reach them.

HTML-code:
[HTML-CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbeqU.png)

I have tried accessing the `<aza-subpage-fixed-footer>` through the normal `.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "aza-subpage-fixed-footer"`. It only returned the following error-code:

Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException

Comment: Can't see any shadow dom or iframe from the image you posted, post the URL and the code you've tried.

Comment: Have you searched? This question has been answered many times